# Script to move files into correspond folders having the exact same name

Tags: batch-file

Hello guys today I am asking you if it is possible to
move the files to the folders which are having the exact same name.

I am not willing to scan and move every files of my computer but
just in certain directory where I will place and exectue the script.

Example

Lets say I have a Folder named "Dogs"
and inside the dogs I have pic001.jpg pic002.jpg pic003.jpg ... pic 999.jpg

```
Dogs/pic001.jpg
Dogs/pic002.jpg
Dogs/pic003.jpg
...
Dogs/pic999.jpg
```

and inside the folder "Dogs" I have also created the folder corresponding to their name.

```
Dogs/pic001/
Dogs/pic002/
Dogs/pic003/
...
Dogs/pic999/
```

I will place the script inside the "Dogs" folder and when executed the script
I want all the files to move to their corresponding folders which are having the EXACT same name.
(before posting this post, I've googled and done some researches but all I could find was
to move files which are having partially same name but not EXACT same name)

so my desired result is going to be

```
Dogs/pic001/pic001.jpg
Dogs/pic002/pic002.jpg
Dogs/pic003/pic003.jpg
...
Dogs/pic999/pic999.jpg

but what I've written above is just an example, I have lot of folders 
named "Cats", "Wolves", "Turtles" and their containing files are named differently. 
Inside the "Cats" it could be photo001.png ... photo999.png
for "Wolves" it could be wolf001.psd ... wolf999.psd
for "Turtles" it could be turtle001.torrent ... turtle999.torrent
and I have already created the folders corresponding to their files names !
```

So in quick summary and clarify in short simple sentences I want :

```
1.a script that will move the files to the folder which are having the exact same name
2.all actions are going to be happen inside the folder which is containing this script
3.files extensions don't matter it can be a photo, video, exe ... etc 
4.I have already created the folders matching to the files names.
5.This script shouldn't be dependant of it's directory's name
which mean if it works inside the "Cats" Folder, it should also work inside the"Dogs" Folder
in short, once this script is made, I don't want to copy paste the directory everytime in use.
```

I tried all my best to explain my idea simply and clearly as possible
sorry for my poor English if you had any problem while reading and understanding my post
English is not my primary language sorry hehe x)
Any helps would be really appreciated

*I am running in windows 10 not MAC

Comment: Something like this should work from the command prompt: `for /f %G in ('dir /b /a-d') do if exist "%~nG" @echo move "%G" "%~nG\%G"` You can remove the `@echo` if this gives you want  you want. In a batch script, you can double the % symbols.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me Mr.Qwerty ! I've made the Batch Script doubling % but unfortunately it did not work ' for /f %%G in ('dir /b /a-d') do if exist "%%~nG" @echo move "%%G" "%~nG\%%G" '

Comment: The `@echo` is intended to show you what items would be moved. You can see if this is what you want. If it is, you would remove the `@echo` before `move.`

Comment: Great Thanks it is working as intended !!